# How can I add a space after the first printf statement?

Tags: c, printf

Random number guessing game in C.

User has 10 guesses before the game will quit if the correct number is not guessed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
int theNumber;
int userGuess;
int counter = 10;
int lowerBound = 1, upperBound = 100;

// seed function
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

// generates number between 1 and 100
theNumber = lowerBound + rand() % (upperBound - lowerBound + 1);

printf("Please guess a number (1-100): ");

for (counter = 9; counter <= 10; counter--) {

    // get users guess
    scanf("%d", &userGuess);

    if (userGuess == theNumber) {
        printf("You guessed it! The number was: %d", theNumber);
        break;
    }

    if (userGuess < theNumber && counter >= 1)
        printf("Your guess was too low. You have %d guesses remaining. Guess higher: ", counter);

    if (userGuess > theNumber && counter >= 1)
        printf("Your guess was too high. You have %d guesses remaining. Guess lower: ", counter);

    if (counter == 0) {
        printf("\nYou ran out of guesses. The number was: %d \n", theNumber);
        break;
    }

}

return 0;

}
```

Sample output:

```
Please guess a number (1-100): 100
Your guess was too high. You have 9 guesses remaining. Guess lower: 90
```

How can I add a space after the first printf statement so that the output looks like this?

Desired output:

```
Please guess a number (1-100): 100

Your guess was too high. You have 9 guesses remaining. Guess lower: 90
```

Comment: I tried that out. If I were to put \n after the first printf statement the users first guess would break to the next line and I don't want that to happen. I would like it to stay to the right on the first line if possible.

Comment: Seriously? Why else did you try? Hint: If you want to print something **after** the input, printing **before** the input logically won't work.

Comment: My apologies. I'm a bit confused. Are you saying it's logically impossible to accomplish what I'm trying to  do?

Comment: printf("\nYour guess was too high. You have %d guesses remaining. Guess lower: ", counter); Note the \n before the your

Comment: I tried that out also however it now prints a space between every line after that. I want to keep the correct / incorrect guess statements bunched up after the first printf statement.

Comment: A space is not a newline in programming (but both are whitespace characters). You ask for newline, so don't talk about spaces. Using the correct phrases greatly enhances readbility and understandablility of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if user enters text like 'one' ! what happens?
**always check for errors**:

```
if (scanf("%d", &userGuess) != 1){
    printf("incorrect input.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

if you need vertical space use `printf("\n");`.
if you need vertical space just once use:

```
if (counter == 9)
    printf("\n");
```

sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int theNumber;
    int userGuess;
    int counter = 10;
    int lowerBound = 1, upperBound = 100;

    // seed function
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    // generates number between 1 and 100
    theNumber = lowerBound + rand() % (upperBound - lowerBound + 1);

    printf("Please guess a number (1-100): ");

    for (counter = 9; counter <= 10; counter--) {

        // get users guess
        if (scanf("%d", &userGuess) != 1){
            printf("incorrect input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        //if (counter == 9)
        printf("\n");

        if (userGuess == theNumber) {
            printf("You guessed it! The number was: %d", theNumber);
            break;
        }

        if (userGuess < theNumber && counter >= 1)
            printf("Your guess was too low. You have %d guesses remaining. Guess higher: ", counter);

        if (userGuess > theNumber && counter >= 1)
            printf("Your guess was too high. You have %d guesses remaining. Guess lower: ", counter);

        if (counter == 0) {
            printf("\nYou ran out of guesses. The number was: %d \n", theNumber);
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about a new blank line in between these two lines you can simply do it by adding`printf("\n");`after your first printf statement.

If you want to put spacing anywhere please use`printf(" ");`this will add space in between.

Use a int and while loop to print as many spaces or new blank lines in between you want.

Example:

```
int main()
{
   int i;
   i = 0;
   while (i < 30)
   {
      printf(" ");
      i++;
   }
   printf("X\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: One of the correct ways to define `main()` - `int main(void) {...}`

Comment: @babon Thanks For pointing out . You basically want to ensure that no argument is passed. Please correct me if i am wrong as I am a beginner.

Comment: `()` - the function takes an unspecified number of arguments. `(void)` - the function takes absolutely no args. You may take this piece of code: http://hastebin.com/muyucoqafa.coffee and play.